# More determinism for `memberd/2`?

Tags: list, prolog

Many systems provide a pure and efficient implementation of `member/2`. In particular, no choice point is left open for:

```
?- member(b,[a,b]).
   true.
```

whereas, a naive implementation of `member/2` produces rather:

```
?- member(b,[a,b]).
   true
;  false.
```

which is certainly correct from a declarative viewpoint, but less efficient.

On the other hand, there are some technical problems with `member/2`. It permits redundant solutions, like in:

```
?- member(a,[a,a]).
   true
;  true.
```

`memberd/2` solves this problem using [`if_/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600/772868) and `(=)/3`.

```
memberd(E, [X|Xs]) :-
   if_(E = X, true, memberd(E, Xs)).

?- memberd(a,[a,a]).
   true.
```

Unfortunately, this definition leaves choice points open again - producing `; false` ("leftover choicepoints") in situations where member does not:

```
?- memberd(X,[a,b]).
   X = a
;  X = b
;  false.    % BAD - to be avoided!

?- member(X,[a,b]).
   X = a
;  X = b.
```

So my question: Is there a definition of `memberd/2` that avoids the choice point as this one above?

Comment: A kind of unit test would be useful. Something like "Hey, guys, make it succeed".

Comment: @dlask: There is only the toplevel that shows you what we want to succeed. Could use `setup_call_cleanup/3` but that is way more confusing.

Comment: I mean, there are many different combinations of parameters and responses, it would be comfortable to have all those checks automated. By the way, is it possible to detect the choice points programmatically?

Comment: Two related questions/remarks: 1) `member(a, [a,a])` succeeds twice, but this could be interpreted as "`a` is member of `[a,a]` twice"; can you explicitly provide in your question your preferred reading? and 2) `member(a, [a, b])` still gives `true; false`; is your idea that a succeeding exactly once is always to be preferred?

Comment: @Boris: Declarative reading is always a reading on ground terms only. A redundant solution thus has absolutely no meaning at all. This becomes maybe more evident if you have several occurences of that goal. Say: `member(a, [a,a]), member(a, [a,a])` the three extra answers have no declarative meaning whatsoever - it would not be the worst idea to use a `once/1` in this particular case. Note that `once/1` cannot be used for every ground goal, because of potential inconsistencies - think of `p:-freeze(_,false).` and the query `q`.

Comment: @Boris: As for `true ; false` this is a performance issue **only**. There are other ways to attack this problem (like [`call_semidet/1`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12942551/772868)) too.

Answer (score 12):

First, we rename `memberd` to `memberd_old` for the sake of clarity.

Then, we implement `memberd_new/2`, which uses lagging and 1st argument indexing to prevent the creation of the useless choicepoint at the end of the list.

```
memberd_new(E,[X|Xs]) :-
   memberd_new_aux(Xs,X,E).

% auxiliary predicate to enable first argument indexing
memberd_new_aux([],E,E).
memberd_new_aux([X1|Xs],X0,E) :-
   if_(E=X0, true, memberd_new_aux(Xs,X1,E)).
```

Let's compare `member/2` (SWI-Prolog builtin predicate), `memberd_old/2`, and `memberd_new/2`!

First, a ground query:

```
?- member(a,[a,a]).
true ;
true.                       % BAD!

?- memberd_old(a,[a,a]).
true.

?- memberd_new(a,[a,a]).
true.
```

Next, another ground query:

```
?- member(a,[a,b]).
true ;                      % BAD!
false.

?- memberd_old(a,[a,b]).
true.

?- memberd_new(a,[a,b]).
true.
```

Now, a query having multiple distinct solutions:

```
?- member(X,[a,b]).
X = a ;
X = b.

?- memberd_old(X,[a,b]).
X = a ;
X = b ;                     % BAD!
false.

?- memberd_new(X,[a,b]).
X = a ;
X = b.
```

#### Edit

The implementation of `memberd_new/2` presented here is deprecated.

I recommend using the newer implementation shown [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31776490/4609915).

Comment: ~ It is a restriction compared to `member/2` or `memberd/2`. Not sure this is a good idea.

Comment: `memberd(a,[a|nonlist])` succeeds, but not in your version

Comment: @false What is the rationale behind `memberd(a, [a|nonlist])` succeeding? The second argument is not even a list?

Comment: @Boris: It is a generalization that has performance advantages. Think of `memberd(a,[a,b,c,d])` which is immediately determinate without visiting the entire list. Conversely, if you would always impose that no generalization is permitted you would have much weaker termination properties (think of the 2nd argument of `append/3`).

Comment: @Boris: and, similar arguments apply to enumerate answers for partial lists, there repeat's aproach produces twice as many answers.

Comment: @Boris: FYI, there is a [100 bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30863784/772868) waiting...

Comment: @false That's great, but I am not able to figure out the intended semantics of `memberd/2`. Reading the answers where you have used it to solve other questions, I get a clear idea of how it can be used to solve the particular problem, but I am not sure I understand its most general meaning.

Comment: @Boris: You know how to ask a question :-)

Answer (score 8):

In this answer we compare three different list-membership predicates:

- `member/2`, a builtin predicate, as implemented in SWI-Prolog.
- `memberd/2`, as defined by the OP:

  ```
  memberd(E,[X|Xs]) :-
     if_(E=X, true, memberd(E,Xs)).
  ```
- `memberd_new/2`, a proposed alternative which is defined like this:

  ```
  memberd_new(E,[X|Xs]) :-
     (  Xs \= [_|_]
     -> E=X
     ;  if_(E=X, true, memberd_new(E,Xs))
     ).
  ```

---

Let's go!

First, some ground queries:

```
?- member(b,[a,b]).
true.
?- memberd(b,[a,b]).
true.
?- memberd_new(b,[a,b]).
true.

?- member(a,[a,a]).
true ; true.                        % BAD
?- memberd(a,[a,a]).
true.
?- memberd_new(a,[a,a]).
true.

?- member(a,[a,b]).
true ; false.                       % BAD 
?- memberd(a,[a,b]).
true.
?- memberd_new(a,[a,b]).
true.
```

Next, some queries having multiple distinct solutions:

```
?- member(X,[a,b]).
X = a ; X = b.
?- memberd(X,[a,b]).
X = a ; X = b ; false.              % BAD
?- memberd_new(X,[a,b]).
X = a ; X = b.
```

Next, a test-case suggested in a comment to
[a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30926352/4609915) which broke the version of `memberd_new/2` presented earlier.

```
?- member(a,[a|nonlist]).
true.
?- memberd(a,[a|nonlist]).
true.
?- memberd_new(a,[a|nonlist]).
true.                               % IMPROVED
```

A variation of above test-case:

```
?- member(X,[a|nonlist]).
X = a.
?- memberd(X,[a|nonlist]).
X = a ; false.                      % BAD
?- memberd_new(X,[a|nonlist]).
X = a.                              % IMPROVED
```

Last, some non-terminating queries:

```
?- member(1,Xs).
  Xs =          [1|_A]
; Xs =       [_A,1|_B]
; Xs =    [_A,_B,1|_C]
; Xs = [_A,_B,_C,1|_D]
...

?- memberd(1,Xs).
  Xs =          [1|_A]
; Xs =       [_A,1|_B], dif(_A,1)
; Xs =    [_A,_B,1|_C], dif(_A,1), dif(_B,1)
; Xs = [_A,_B,_C,1|_D], dif(_A,1), dif(_B,1), dif(_C,1) 
...

?- memberd_new(1,Xs).
  Xs =          [1|_A]
; Xs =       [_A,1|_B], dif(_A,1)
; Xs =    [_A,_B,1|_C], dif(_A,1), dif(_B,1)
; Xs = [_A,_B,_C,1|_D], dif(_A,1), dif(_B,1), dif(_C,1)
...
```

Answer (score 6):

There's more... Suppose, we implement `memberD/2` based on `memberd_t/3`:

```
memberD(X,Xs) :- memberd_t(X,Xs,true).
```

How does **that** compare to `memberd/2`, as defined by the OP in the question?

Let's re-run some queries!

```
?- memberd(a,[a,a]), memberd(a,[a,b]), memberd(b,[a,b]), 
   memberD(a,[a,a]), memberD(a,[a,b]), memberD(b,[a,b]).
true.                             % all of these succeed deterministiaclly

?- memberd(X,[a,b]).
X = a ; X = b ; false.            % could be better
?- memberD(X,[a,b]).
X = a ; X = b ; false.            % could be better

?- memberd(a,[a|nonlist]), memberD(a,[a|nonlist]).
true.                             % both succeed deterministically

?- memberd(X,[a|nonlist]).
X = a ; false.                    % could be better
?- memberD(X,[a|nonlist]).
X = a ; false.                    % could be better
```

In above queries, `memberd/2` and `memberD/2` give the same answers and leave behind superfluous choice-points in the same instances.

Let's dig a little deeper! Consider the following queries using `memberd_t/3` with corner-cases:

```
?- memberd_t(a,[a|nonlist],T).
T = true.                         % OK
?- memberd_t(b,[a|nonlist],T).
false.                            % missing: `T = false`
?- memberd_t(X,[a|nonlist],T).
  T = true, X = a 
; false.                          % missing: `T = false, dif(X,a)`
```

This is not quite what I expected / wanted to get.  What can we do? Basically, I see two options:

1. Accept this discrepancy and proclaim: "These queries are corner-cases of no importance."
2. Build an implementation of `memberd_t/3` that can handle these cases.

Both options have strengths and weaknesses. 
In the following we implement `memberd_new_t/3` which both handles the corner cases and reduces the creation of superfluous choice-points.

Warning: ugly code ahead!

```
memberd_new_t(E,Xs0,Truth) :-
   (  Xs0 \= [_|_]
   -> Truth = false
   ;  Truth = false,
      freeze(Xs0, Xs0\=[_|_])
   ;  Xs0 = [X|Xs],
      (  Xs \= [_|_]
      -> =(E,X,Truth)
      ;  if_(E=X,Truth=true,memberd_new_t(E,Xs,Truth))
      )
   ).
```

Let's check if we produce fewer useless choicepoints with `memberd_new_t/3`!

```
?- memberd_t(X,[a,b],true).
X = a ; X = b ; false.              % suboptimal
?- memberd_new_t(X,[a,b],true).
X = a ; X = b.                      % BETTER

?- memberd_t(X,[a|nonlist],true).
X = a ; false.                      % suboptimal
?- memberd_new_t(X,[a|nonlist],true).
X = a.                              % BETTER
```

*Alright!* So what about above corner cases?

```
?- memberd_t(a,[a|nonlist],T).
T = true.                           % OK
?- memberd_new_t(a,[a|nonlist],T).
T = true.                           % OK

?- memberd_t(b,[a|nonlist],T).
false.                              % BAD
?- memberd_new_t(b,[a|nonlist],T).
T = false.                          % OK

?- memberd_t(X,[a|nonlist],T).
  T = true, X = a 
; false.                            % BAD
?- memberd_new_t(X,[a|nonlist],T).
  T =  true,     X=a
; T = false, dif(X,a).              % OK
```

It works! At last, consider the most general queries:

```
?- memberd_t(X,Xs,T).          
  T=false, Xs = []            
; T=true , Xs = [X       |_A]        
; T=false, Xs = [_A         ], dif(X,_A)
; T=true , Xs = [_A, X   |_B], dif(X,_A)
; T=false, Xs = [_A,_B      ], dif(X,_A), dif(X,_B)
; T=true , Xs = [_A,_B, X|_C], dif(X,_A), dif(X,_B)
; T=false, Xs = [_A,_B,_C   ], dif(X,_A), dif(X,_B), dif(X,_C)
...

?- memberd_new_t(X,Xs,T).
  T=false, freeze(Xs,Xs\=[_|_])
; T=true ,                       Xs = [ X      |_A]
; T=false, freeze(_B,_B\=[_|_]), Xs = [_A      |_B], dif(X,_A)
; T=true ,                       Xs = [_A, X   |_B], dif(X,_A)
; T=false, freeze(_C,_C\=[_|_]), Xs = [_A,_B   |_C], dif(X,_A), dif(X,_B)
; T=true ,                       Xs = [_A,_B, X|_C], dif(X,_A), dif(X,_B)
; T=false, freeze(_D,_D\=[_|_]), Xs = [_A,_B,_C|_D], dif(X,_A), dif(X,_B), dif(X,_C)
...
```

For these corner cases, `memberd_new_t/3` is more like `memberd/3` than  `memberd_t/3`:

```
?- memberd(X,Xs).
  Xs = [ X            |_A]
; Xs = [_A, X         |_B], dif(X,_A)
; Xs = [_A,_B, X      |_C], dif(X,_A), dif(X,_B)
; Xs = [_A,_B,_C, X   |_D], dif(X,_A), dif(X,_B), dif(X,_C)
; Xs = [_A,_B,_C,_D, X|_E], dif(X,_A), dif(X,_B), dif(X,_C), dif(X,_D)
...
```