# member function giving odd results.

Tags: recursion, prolog

I have written a member function, to check if an element exists in a list.

```
member(X, [X|_]).
member(X, [_|Y]) :- member(X, Y).
```

I load the .pl file into SWI prolog, and I get no warnings or errors pertaining to member.  I test the member function using...

```
member(A, [1,2,3,4]).
```

This, obviously should return false.  Instead I get

```
 A = 1
```

Then when I try to enter new commands, the ide just shows me the key I typed, and says unknown action "what ever key i pressed"

I think my member function is sound, as it matches one written by my professor.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why should `member(A, [1,2,3,4])` *obviously return false*? It should obviously succeed for `A = 1` as well as for `A = 2`, `A = 3`, and `A = 4`. When it shows `A = 1` you need to press SPACE or `;` to see the next result, if there is one (per the Prolog documentation).

Comment: The chances are, this predicate was not written by your professor. `member/2`, with this implementation, has been around for decades I think? I've seen it in a dead tree textbook published in 1986 but I guess it predates the book.

Comment: @Boris: It is pretty recent ~less than 10 years that `member/2` became a true built-in. So it is quite natural to provide its definition.

Comment: @false In SWI-Prolog it is not a true built-in, it is defined in a library. The same for YAP I think. I don't know the GNU-Prolog implementation but there it shouldn't matter, right? Still, my point was rather that this definition has been around for quite a while.

Comment: @Boris: In SWI you can still add your own definition of `member/2`, like `member(1,2).` However, once you used the implicitly defined version, you are stuck with it. It is a built-in (that you cannot redefine) in SICStus 4. In YAP it is not defined at all (at least the version I tried, YAP has recently some strange changes that makes it difficult to follow). In GNU it cannot be redefined. Anyway, at least the Prolog prologue provides the first  [complete defnition](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue#member).

Comment: @Boris, AFAIK in SWI Prolog built-in's are also implemented in the library. But they can be autoloaded (library usage may not be declared). About implementation of `member/2` in SWI and others: It's just a syntactic sugar or whatever you want sugar ;). Take any else predicate or create your own with similar semantic you will see how it behaves (when failure isn't hidden. http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=member/2

Comment: @AntonDanilov I am not sure what you mean by "syntactic sugar". If you look at the [standard library implementation](https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/swipl-devel/blob/3bb20443c682b78c2cc6f8add52ac779f9cf7919/library/lists.pl#L98-L116) you should notice that it is indeed different from the one shown here, in order to get rid of the choice point in some cases.

Comment: @AntonDanilov I guess I have been using "built-in" to mean "implemented in the underlying language (C)", and "library predicate" to mean "implemented in Prolog". I really don't know if this is at all correct....

Answer (score 0):

You have called predicate `member/2` in the **i/o mode(o, i)** e.i. first argument *free (unbound)* variable and the second is *bound* variable.

In that mode (despite its name) `member/2` actually doesn't test element against list membership but simply enumerates list elements one-by-one and, finally, when no elements are remained, it fails (predicates **fail** in terms of *logic programming*, not **return false** ).

This predicate often used in so called *failure driven control* technique, e.g.:

trivial example when enumerated list elements are simply written

```
 ?- forall( member(X, [1,2,3,4]), write( X ) ).
```

Note, in this case will be no failure after list is exhausted.
To ensure this, the last clause is added, such that is meaning "the predicate successed at all".

```
 p( List, Action ) :- generator( Variant, List ), side_effect_action( Variant ), fail.
 p( _ , _ ).

 generator( X, L ) :- member( X, L ).
```

Comment: The documentation to `member/2` is usually quite (too?) succint, see for example the [SWI-Prolog manual](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=member/2): "True when `Elem` is a member of `List`". When `Elem` is a variable, "is a member" translates to "unifies with member". I am pointing this out just to make clear that nothing in the implementation or documentation of `member/2` claims that it only tests whether a ground element is inside a ground list.

Comment: Agree. I only meant (by my personal expierence) that member/2 may be interpeted lop-sidely due to its typical usage (X is member of Xs) .

Comment: Typically, if you want to test for membership of a ground element in ground list you'd take `memberchk/2` since it is both more efficient and leaves no choice points. All the uses of `member/2` that **cannot** be replaced by `memberchk/2` involve a first argument that is **not** ground; for example, `?- member(a(X), [a(1), b(2), a(3)])`.

Comment: Although I gotta say, "X **is** member of Xs" already hints that what is meant is "X unifies with element(s) of Xs". There are a few of those in the SWI-Prolog documentation, and I think elsewhere too. For example, "`min_member(Min, List)` True when Min is the smallest member in the standard order of terms." but then: `?- min_member(2, [1, X]). X = 2.` (!?!)

Comment: @Boris In my answer I told about non-ground first sargument and ground list. For me,  it's the one of typical usages too. :)

Comment: I already gave you an upvote because I thought it is a good answer :-)

Comment: I am not sure I know what you mean by "appropriate" and how to mark it. BTW, the last part of your answer is a bit dubious and I am not sure I understand it. Do you mean to say that you try to manually add the trailing choice point even if it is not there?

Comment: @Boris I 'm about this: One can generate members of a list:

    ?- member(X,[1,2,3]).
    X = 1 ;
    X = 2 ;
    X = 3 ;
    No

 https://www.cpp.edu/~jrfisher/www/prolog_tutorial/2_7.html

Comment: If you try the library version of `member/2` in SWI-Prolog you will see there is no "No" or "false" after the last solution. So I still don't understand if you think this is the _desired_ behaviour and trying to emulate it, or if there is something more going on.

Comment: I wouldn't really refer to `member(A, [1,2,3,4])` as a *mode of operation*. In Prolog, a query is a query and Prolog simply tries to make that query succeed and will instantiate any variables, if it can, in order to result in that success. Querying `member(1, [1,2,3,4])` simply succeeds. Querying `member(A, [1,2,3,4])` succeeds if Prolog instantiates `A` with 1, 2, 3, or 4. And `member(1, L)` succeeds on `L` of `[1|_]`, `[_,1|_]`, `[_,_,1|_]`, etc...

Comment: @lurker I am not sure how you mean it, but querying `member(1, [1,2,3,4])` succeeds with a choice point, and fails if backtracked into. Which is why the whole [`memberd/2` story](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30924607/1812457)

Comment: @Boris yes you're right, I was a little sloppy with my words of "simply succeeds". I guess it succeeds but not so simply. :) My overall point, though, was that there aren't different "modes" of operation for a predicate.